# Works on windows but gives Segmentation fault on Ubuntu

Tags: c++

So I've seen this sort of problem in different threads here but couldn't find the answer needed for this case...

Like I mentioned in the title, my  code works just fine on Visual Studio 2013 with no memory leaks or anything of that sort but when ran through Ubuntu's platform it runs up to the point where the copy constructor is called and then stops when setting the second node as new, I've tried switching the location of 'const' in that constructor's title to be after the function or after the type name and it just didn't work at all then, I tried changing the order of the functions and that just didn't do anything, I tried calling the copy constructor in a different way which also just gave the same results, I also tried showing this to my practice teacher, you can guess the outcome of that though since I'm still here writing this thread :P

What am I missing then?

The code below represents a **Cycle Linked List** with 2 data types in each node:
.hpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MyLinkedList{
private:
    class Node{
    public:
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
        string key;
        double data;

        Node(const string key, const double data)
        {
            this->next = this->prev = NULL;
            this->key = key;
            this->data = data;
        }

        Node(const Node* node)
        {
            this->next = this->prev = NULL;
            this->key = node->key;
            this->data = node->data;
        }
    };//END OF NODE

    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

public:
    MyLinkedList();
    void add(const string& key, const double& data);
    MyLinkedList(const MyLinkedList& MLL);
    ~MyLinkedList();
    bool empty();
    void printList();
    MyLinkedList& operator=(const MyLinkedList&);
    int remove(const string&);
    bool isInList(const string, double&);
    double sumList();
};
```

.cpp (partial):

```
#include "MyLinkedList.hpp"

MyLinkedList::MyLinkedList(){
    head = tail = NULL;
}

void MyLinkedList::add(const string& key, const double& data){
    if (empty()){
        head = new Node(key, data);
        tail = head->next = head->prev = head;
        tail->next = tail->prev = head;
        return;
    }

    tail->next = new Node(key, data);//**(Segmentation fault HERE)**
    tail->next->prev = tail;
    tail = tail->next;
    tail->next = head;

    head->prev = tail;
}


MyLinkedList::MyLinkedList(const MyLinkedList& MLL){
    if (MLL.head == NULL){
        head = tail = NULL;
        return;
    }

    Node* N1 = MLL.head;
    do{
        add(N1->key, N1->data);//<--falls on the second time
        N1 = N1->next;
    } while (N1 != MLL.head);
}

bool MyLinkedList::empty(){
return head==NULL;
}

int main(){
    MyLinkedList A;
    A.add("key1", 1);
    A.printList();
    A.add("key4", 2);
    A.add("key3", 3);
    A.add("key4", 4);
    A.printList();
    cout << "sum: " << A.sumList() << endl;
    MyLinkedList A2(A);// <--Segmentation fault within.
    A2.printList();
}
```

Comment: `tail->next = new Node(key, data);` You should check and ensure that `tail != nullptr;` before calling this. You also should have a check that `&MLL != this` in your copy constructor. There's room for more improvement I'm sure.

Comment: You tried everything except actually debugging the code

Comment: tail wasn't anything which seem to have been the problem.
And tenfour, how'd I know exactly where it falls without debugging it? ._.

Comment: Debugging means more than just "running it under a debugger". Anyway I didn't mean to be short; cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't initialize the pointers in the copy constructor like you do in the default constructor, so they are dangling when you call `add`. Do

```
MyLinkedList::MyLinkedList(const MyLinkedList& MLL) {
  head = tail = NULL;

  // Rest as before
```

Several side notes: Since you're using MSVC 2013, wich has (limited) C++11 support, you could also write

```
// nullptr is the typesafe C++11 way to write NULL
Node* head = nullptr;
Node* tail = nullptr;
```

in the class and would never have to worry about it again. Another style note is that it's arguably better style to initialise data members in the ctor init list rather than inside the constructor body like so:

```
MyLinkedList::MyLinkedList(const MyLinkedList& MLL)
 : head(nullptr),
   tail(nullptr) {
  ...
```

Because this also works with members that are not default-constructible, such as references.

Comment: Yup, that was it tyvm :p How comes VS13 actually compiled it though and gave me the expected results when I was using those uninitialized pointers? And whatever the case, is there anything you could suggest that'd help preventing such things from reoccurring again in the future?

Comment: To find out why exactly it worked with VS13 is a bit difficult (you'd have to step through the machine code). It'll have to do with the state the stack and registers happened to be left in after the output to `cout`. It's quite possible that debug and release builds behave differently in such cases, or that changing apparently unrelated code triggers the error later. To debug that sort of thing, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is an invaluable tool.